# Changing the color of FPPopover controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, fppopover

I have Downloaded FPPopover controller code form [Link](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover)

it consist the some popover colors as green,red,yellow,light gray..

But in that code i am not able to change the popover color as real popover color as in iPad

Please go through the code in the above [Link](https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover) and help me...

Thanks..

Comment: it uses CoreGraphics to draw gradients..i don't think you will be able to edit it yourself

Comment: have you check or not...? @honey-bunny its a editable and very easy.

Comment: Please provide that code modifications @NitinGohel ....for getting the real ipad popover color...

Answer (score 1):

hey its simple you just need to change value here in this example

**FPPopoverView.h**

```
typedef enum {
    FPPopoverBlackTint,
    FPPopoverLightGrayTint,
    FPPopoverGreenTint,
    FPPopoverRedTint,
    FPPopoverDefaultTint = FPPopoverRedTint
} FPPopoverTint;
```

you can check change with  `FPPopoverDefaultTint = FPPopoverRedTint` with `FPPopoverDefaultTint = FPPopoverLightGrayTint`

i just tested and i put `FPPopoverRedTint`

**Output is**

[image]

Comment: Thanks......But i need the real ipad popover color....for that i need to create new enum...so  what colors i need to put in that enum for getting the real ipad popover color...

Comment: R:11 G:17 B:47 you have to set its main popover color and its glass effect rgb is R:60 G:74 B:97 approx

Comment: you just see how to set other enum in FPPopoverView.h and .m then you have to crate your own enum with my above comment RGB color :)